# How do I configure a Smart Playlist to show songs not in other Playlists?

Tags: itunes, smart-playlist

I have a ton of songs that I classify in named playlists, and would like to have an easier way of knowing if a song has been previously classified or not. The thought occurred to me to make a Smart Playlist that will show me songs that meet the following requirements:

- Media Type must be Music (excludes Music Videos, Movies, TV Shows, Books, Podcasts, etc.)
- Must not exist in any playlist within the parent Classification folder.
- Must not exist in the "Unclassifiable" folder.

I can't get the Smart Playlist to populate with all remaining songs:

[image: Smart Playlist Rules for 'Unclassified']

Is it possible to create a Smart Playlist showing all songs not in another playlist?

Comment: It's supposed to be "Is Not" Genres, actually, but it's a moot point. Either way it's set, I get 0 results. I've also tried using "Media Kind is Music" and only specifying the playlists that should have music excluded from.

Comment: That should work. Maybe you should double check your "Unclassifiable" playlist to make sure it doesn't contain all the songs in your library?

Comment: 0 items in Unclassifiable (which is a static playlist, not a Smart Playlist) for the moment. 0 items in Unclassified.

Comment: Hm, I created a similar Smart Playlist in my iTunes and it works fine http://cl.ly/LRnP

Comment: I guess it just takes a long time to populate. Because sure enough I come back today and it's suddenly working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the screenshot, or at least the correct version, is sufficient:

[image: Smart Playlist Settings]

No doubt in part to my tens of thousands of songs, and only a few hundreds currently classified, the playlist took sometime to populate. After reading Kyle's comment, I looked at the playlist and nearly my whole library is now present.

So the answer to this problem can only logically be:

Patience

Comment: I'm glad it worked finally, but it shouldn't have taken that much time. I have ~7500 songs in my library and iTunes is able to make smart playlists instantly.

Comment: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Osc.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Osc.png)