# How to create iTunes smart playlist of playlists

Tags: itunes, playlist, smart-playlist

I'm using iTunes 12.5.3 on Windows 10. I am trying to create a smart playlist that selects songs from other playlists, limited by storage. (Much like in [How do I configure a Smart Playlist to show songs not in other Playlists?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74118/how-do-i-configure-a-smart-playlist-to-show-songs-not-in-other-playlists))

I have a number of these lists already, which I created several years ago, with a previous version of iTunes.

My problem now is that I am unable to select any particular playlist in the smart playlist dialog. The playlist name is defaulted to "Music", as shown here:

[image: Screenshot]

Further, if I open one of my existing examples, the dialog will show the playlist(s) I'm harvesting, but *won't let me edit the playlist names*.

What is going on here? How can I fix things so this works?

I know that an alternative solution is recreate the rules that form the source playlists in a new smart playlist, with the additional size restriction. This is what I'm now doing as a work-around, but it would be preferable to just get the feature working like it once did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi placed exactly the same question in one of the Apple forums, and I received [this helpful reply](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7870641?start=0&tstart=0):

> The playlist selection drop down has been broken in the last few
>   builds and doesn't expand properly, however once you have selected it
>   the up and down cursor keys should still let you chose a list to refer
>   to.